# JQuery Datepicker Does Not Render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am  experiencing an issue whereby a datepicker control does not render on my HTML page. When  viewing the error on the console I see: `SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'`

My code is as follows:

```js
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: check the edit I made on this one. click on the input field. 
Does it seem to work ?

Comment: It works in  the  code snippet but  for some strange reason it does not in my mvc view. I have the <input type="text" id="datepicker"  /> in a  @Html.BeginForm()

Comment: do you get any error message in the browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have **to move your scripts before the end body tag** `</body>`, try this :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> <!-- fixed the url -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- YOUR CODE START HERE -->
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<!-- YOUR CODE END HERE -->

<!-- YOUR SCRIPTS START HERE -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<!-- YOUR SCRIPTS END HERE -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in  the  code snippet but  for some strange reason it does not in my mvc view. I have the <input type="text" id="datepicker"  /> in a  @Html.BeginForm()

Comment: just surouned your script like this : `$(document).ready( function () { ...your script code go here... });` - i edited the answer